# Botframework bot not responding to facebook messages

Tags: botframework

I have created a using the botframework (nodejs on Azure). It works well on Skype. I have everything configured correctly on both the Botframework site and on Facebook but when I send a message as the admin for the page the I do not receive any responses back from the bot.

I tried to recreate another bot using the sample code and that does not work as well.

I have the webhooks configured and subscribed as well.

Comment: I'm not seeing any specific issues with the Facebook channel (and tested it with one of my test bots), so I 'm thinking some sort of configuration issue. Can you share with me the bot handle for either of the bots so I can look in the logs?

Comment: APA is the current one. I removed the other one to test with FB's sample code and it works well.

Comment: Can you share some code? and the setup info. Have you tested with Emulator. Also try with ngrok once.

Comment: Maybe something related with this ? https://mumbrella.com.au/facebook-has-stopped-messenger-bots-heres-what-you-need-to-know-509654